# Different GDP figure for same country

Tags: gdp

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)_per_capita
This link shows GDP of India = 2191 under the column with the heading IMF

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asian_countries_by_GDP_(PPP)_per_capita
This link shows India GDP = 7333

This is confusing. I am not sure what does this means. What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at two different measures; 1. Nominal GDP per capita, 2. GDP at purchasing power parity (adjusted for the fact that price levels are different in different countries). They should not be equal.

Also, nominal GDP is for the year 2019, and GDP at PPP is estimate for 2021, so even if they would be the same measure GDP is not fixed, it changes over time.

Comment: Thanks. So is GDP at PPP a more accurate prediction for how prosperous a nation is? Also, when you search on google 'GDP per capita of Kenya', it shows a graph and number is that by default, a nominal GDP?

Comment: @Daniel GDP at PPP is better for international comparisons. If you want to compare GDPs of 2 countries you should use GDP at PPP. You have to read what the page you googled says.